# Why Rest Api in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

What is the main reason that we go for Rest Api in SharePoint 2013. Already we have Client Object Model for implementing application. Anybody can please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The Client Side Object Model is built upon the REST API so that is one reason for it to exist.  For good JavaScript developers they may like the simplicity of the REST API.  For people trying to keep their page size to a minimum, they may appreciate forgoing the size of the CSOM and its dependencies.  Lastly, in mash up scenarios with other tools, having an easy way to address content via REST urls makes for better interoperability with other tools instead of relying on a product specific API (i.e. the CSOM).